# javascript get strings between bracket [ ]

Tags: javascript

in my paragraph I have to get the string between brackets [ ]

ie)

```
<p id="mytext">
    this is my paragraph but I have [code1] and there is another bracket [code2].
</p>
```

on my JavaScript I have go through all strings and get result of array only as 
"code1" and "code2"

thank you in advance!

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to retrieve those substrings.

The problem is that JS doesn't have lookbehinds. Then, you can retrieve the text with the brackets, and then remove them manually:

```js
(document.getElementById('mytext').textContent
  .match(/\[.+?\]/g)     // Use regex to get matches
  || []                  // Use empty array if there are no matches
).map(function(str) {    // Iterate matches
  return str.slice(1,-1) // Remove the brackets
});
```

Alternatively, you can use a capturing group, but then you must call `exec` iteratively (instead of a single `match`):

```js
var str = document.getElementById('mytext').textContent,
    rg = /\[(.+?)\]/g,
    match;
while(match = rg.exec(str)) // Iterate matches
  match[1];                 // Do something with it
```

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Yes, but since JS doesn't have lookbehinds, I should use a capturing group, which aren't retrieved by a global `match`, so I should use `exec` in a loop, and I don't think it would be much simpler.

Comment: Well, I included this alternative too.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Well, the loop can `push` each substring to an array. That is left as an exercise for the reader.